# Android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, image, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611822/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget)

I have been getting this `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget` error from long time.I have many images(png's) which i am using in the application.The total size of all the images would be in Kb's. I went across various post related to this topic but they are related to devices.I am encountering this problem in `emulator` rather than any device, its working perfectly fine on all the device i have tested .What can be done for this problem.

```
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.curious.solutions.finalautoistdiary/com.curious.solutions.finalautoistdiary.ServiceAdd}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:684)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at com.curious.solutions.finalautoistdiary.ServiceAdd.onCreate(ServiceAdd.java:77)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     ... 11 more
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     ... 23 more
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:173)
11-08 12:18:53.259: E/AndroidRuntime(1626):     ... 26 more
```

Comment: could you post some related code and stack trace?

Comment: At most, this exception is thrown when using bitmap manipulation in the UI Thread. You can workaround that by opening/manipulation Bitmaps in a Runnable

Comment: Here you go: [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError%3A+bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget)

Comment: I am loading all the images from drawable and in xml file so Bitmaps i am quite confused about it. can u explain in bit details

Comment: This has been asked dozens of times before.

Comment: @PareshMayani i visited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108169/bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-error-on-android this question and went through it in details but then its regarding images and i have small pngs which hardly eat up 1 mb of memory so why this issue when android provides 16 mb for each app

Comment: @pgsandstrom though it has been asked no proper solution .. i have cleaned the project as per some of the solutions and reset the adb as well but no use after it moves from 1 activity to other it gives me the error.. ! thats why i have to post it again

Comment: Loading from where? Local or Web? Are you facing issue just because of your code? What code you are trying for loading images?

Comment: i am loading all the locally images from `drawable` folder and most of the most of them are there in `XML` just where the images are supposed to be changed at runtime i am using
`img_services.setImageResource(img_services.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.services2));`